# Azure Automation / Runbooks / Authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I would like to run a Azure Automation Runbook (PowerShell) and run
connect-PnPOnline or connect-MicrosoftExchange

clientid & clientsecret will be deprecating
User is MFA enabled

Can't I connect trough managed identity or keyvault or something else?
Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you briefly explain what exactly the issue or blocker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Run connect-PnPOnline or connect-MicrosoftExchange trough managed identity:

I tried authenticating to the required conections using *Azure PowerShell* as well as *Azure Automation runbook* as follow:

***SystemAssigned Managed Identity:***

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://microsoftapc.sharepoint.com/teams/<Site_Name>"-ManagedIdentity
```

***UserAssigned Managed Identity:***

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url ""-ManagedIdentity -UserAssignedManagedIdentityObjectId <ObjectId of UserAssigned Managed Identity>
```

***Client_ID & Client_secret:***

```
Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell
connect-pnponline -url "https://microsoftapc.sharepoint.com/teams/<Site_Name>"-ClientId "48b4f657-904f-496d-b02a-49cc492b3ee3" -ClientSecret "Tis8Q~Pxn3F2t8kllVCV5pCC2u2SMkxcSEeOrds2" -WarningAction Ignore
```

***Output(AZ Powershell):***

[image]

***Azure runbook:***

First of all, Add the required modules by going to `Automation Account -> Shared Resources -> Modules -> Add a Module`

[image]

To check whether modules are successfully imported, Give

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope AllUsers
Get-command -Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

[image]

***Azure PowerShell:***

[image]

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization "xxxxx" -ManagedIdentityAccountId  "<UserManagedIdentityID>"
```

*References:*

Check here for other possible ways to [Connect-PnPOnline](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html#examples) &
[connect-ExchangeOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online-powershell-using-azure-automation-accounts-with-user-assigned-managed-identities).

Comment: Hi Jahnavi

This is really helpfull. Really sorry I didn't answer your question earlier?
I lost track of this.

I'll try this next week